# Location of core theme functions?

Tags: theming

Where can i find the core theme function code (D7)? I would like to use the table theme function as a template for a new theme function I'm writing.

Arnold

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [API Docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal) on [Drupal.org](http://drupal.org).  There you will be able to find the description on how to use the functions as well as the actual code of the function.  For your use, here is [theme_table()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_table/7).  The actual function is in "includes/theme.inc, line 1631" as stated in the `theme_table()` documentation page.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [themeable functions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--theme.api.php/group/themeable/7) in the API and more generally you can search for [theme_](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/theme_).